# Memory problem after SQL selection in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a memory problem in Java, so I'm asking you this question.

Run the select query with Mybatis and put it in the List object.

Usually, the amount of inquiry results is between 1,000,000 and 3,000,000 or a little more.

I understand that the memory increases when putting it in List objects after importing such a large amount of query results.

However, the increased memory is not released after returning the List object above.

So I also null-processed List  objects before returning.

However, the allocated memory has not been released.

For your information, select query results cannot be paged.

Can I release the allocated memory?

The Java version is 1.8.0_302.

Below is a simple sauce for example.

```
enter code here

public class ExVO {
   private String a;
   private String b;
   private String c;
   private String d;
   private String e;
   private String f;
}


public String getExcel(vo) {

  List<ExVO> list = exMapper.getList(vo);

  if(list.size() > 0){
    list = null;
    return "good";
  }else{
    return "bad";
  }
}
```

Comment: `list.clear()`.

Comment: There are many things to consider here. First of all even if you null out the contents of the list (by using `List#clear` as is mentioned above), this would simply remove the references. If those objects are referenced anywhere else in your code, they won't be eligible for garbage collection. On top of that, clearing out your list will not automatically result in freed up memory. GC is an async process so it may take some time. I suggest you profile your application to get a better insight as to what is happening.